# Google Maps API - set zoom level based on

Tags: google-maps

I have the following code, with which I am trying to set the google maps zoom level dependant on a distance entered in a seperate field.

However it seems that my map is not respecting this code, and can't see what I did wrong here.

```
var dis = document.getElementById('distance-submit').value;

if(dis != "" || dis != null)
{
  var zoomlevel= 13;
  if(dis >=0 && dis < 3)
    zoomlevel= 18;
  if(dis >=3 && dis < 5)
    zoomlevel= 19;
  if(dis >=5 && dis < 10)
    zoomlevel= 15;
  if(dis >= 25 && dis <= 50)
    zoomlevel = 9;
  if(dis > 50 && dis <=100)
    zoomlevel =8;
  if(dis > 100)
    zoomlevel =7;

  console.log(zoomlevel)
  var map;
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longi);

  var mapOptions = {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: zoomlevel,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

Comment: Try this and compare with your code http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/804/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 var dis = document.getElementById('distance-submit').value;
 dis = parseInt( dis);
```